# My UIImage doesn't drop to the bottom of the screen when it's placed in the Delegate function

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsthread, uidynamicanimator

My code drops an UIImage to the bottom of the screen. But it's not working when I place the same code in **isMyUIViewControllerDelegateTriggered**. This is the same thread isn't it??

**MyUIViewController.m**

```
@interface MyUIViewController () <UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DropitBehavior *dropitBehavior;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *jobLoadView;

@end

@synthesize someUIImage;

id refToSelf;  /* Tried this to have a ref to the UIView, but doesn't work. */
static DropitBehavior * dropit;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    refToSelf = self;
    dropit = [[DropitBehavior alloc] init];

    /* Placed inhere, this code works!
    DropitBehavior * dropit = [refToSelf dropitBehavior];
    [dropit addItem:someUIImage]; */

    startupManager = [[StartupManager alloc] init];
    [startupManager setDelegate:refToSelf];
    [startupManager start];
}

- (DropitBehavior *)dropitBehavior
{
    if (!_dropitBehavior) {
        _dropitBehavior = [[DropitBehavior alloc] init];
        [self.animator addBehavior:_dropitBehavior];
    }
    return _dropitBehavior;
}

- (UIDynamicAnimator *)animator
{
    if (!_animator) {
        _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.jobLoadView];
        _animator.delegate = self;
    }
    return _animator;
}


-(void)isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered:(NSString *) errorcode {        
    /* The startup manager code triggers 5 time, so I can make a loading effect. */

    /* Doesn't work when I place the code inhere. */
    dropit = [refToSelf dropitBehavior];

    if ([dropit isKindOfClass:[DropitBehavior class]]) {
       NSLog(@"is kind of class drop it ");
       [dropit addItem:someUIImage];
    }
}
```

**DropitBehavior.m**

```
@interface DropitBehavior()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIGravityBehavior *gravity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollisionBehavior *collider;
@end

@implementation DropitBehavior

/* Singleton */
static DropitBehavior *sharedSingleton;

+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        sharedSingleton = [[DropitBehavior alloc] init];
    }
}

- (UIGravityBehavior *)gravity
{
    if (!_gravity) {
        _gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] init];
        _gravity.magnitude = 0.9;
    }
    return _gravity;
}

- (UICollisionBehavior *)collider
{
    if (!_collider) {
        _collider = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] init];
        _collider.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    }
    return _collider;
}

- (void)addItem:(id <UIDynamicItem>)item
{
    [self.gravity addItem:item];
    [self.collider addItem:item];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    [self addChildBehavior:self.gravity];
    [self addChildBehavior:self.collider];
    return self;
}

@end
```

**StartupManager.m**

```
@implementation StartupManager

JSONParser * jsonParser;
HTTPConnection * httpConnection;
static StartupManager *sharedSingleton;
@synthesize delegate;

+ (void)initialize {

    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized) {
        initialized = YES;
        sharedSingleton = [[StartupManager alloc] init];
        jsonParser = [[JSONParser alloc] init];
        httpConnection = [[HTTPConnection alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void) doingSomeStuff {

        [httpConnection setDelegate:self];
        [httpConnection postRequestToSomeServer:@"some.instance.inthe.cloud";
}

-(void)isHTTPConnectionDelegateTriggered:(NSData *)jsonPost {

    [jsonParser setDelegate:self];
    [jsonParser parseJSON:jsonPost];
}

-(void)isJSONParserDelegateTriggered:(NSString *) message {

    */ this gets called periodically and that has to do a loading screen animation. /*
    [delegate isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered:message];
}
```

**StartupManager.h**

```
@class StartupManager;

@protocol StartupManagerDelegate

@required
    -(void)isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered:(NSString *) errorcode;
@end

@interface StartupManager : NSObject <JSONParserDelegate, HTTPConnectionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<StartupManagerDelegate>  delegate;

- (void) doingSomeStuff;
```

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction? Otherwise I'll have to ask the Grandfather.

Comment: Do you know that the isMyUIViewControllerDelegateTriggered: method is executed?

Comment: yes, it get's triggered!

Comment: Where are you calling isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered: from? You need to provide more details about where and when you call that method.

Comment: isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered is called at some point in time. And then the UIImage needs to drop, showing the user that the app is loading stuff.

Comment: If you log dropit in isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered:, does it give you a  DropitBehavior object?

Comment: @rdelmar yes I've added `if ([dropit isKindOfClass:[DropitBehavior class]])`

Comment: Shouldn't `@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;` be `@property (nonatomic, assign) id<StartupManagerDelegate> delegate;`? Then in your `MyUIViewController ` class where do you set this `delegate` to `self` so it will use the `isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered:` in that class?

Comment: @Popeye I'm sorry I made a mistake it's still early :). It still doesn't work. I've added the new code that I tried.

Comment: I also tried making DropitBehaviour a static class and placing it outside the viewDidLoad, making it globally accessible. STILL doesn't work :S

Comment: I've made DropitBehaviour a Singleton Class. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding the [UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  It doesn't start an animation for you, it just lets you know that the animation state has changed.

So you normally wouldn't start your animation from a delegate method.  In any case, the code you posted doesn't implement any of the delegate methods.  The only way to start the animation with the code as posted is to explicitly invoke `isMyUIViewControllerDelegateTriggered`

When do you want it to start?  `viewDidLoad` is too early.  `viewDidAppear` would normally be the earliest reasonable time for something you expect the user to see.

Comment: I made a mistake, the delegate is called **isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered**. So the startup manager triggers delegates and I use that to show a loading screen with falling images.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? I still haven't figured this one out.

Comment: Can you post the code in start up manager that makes the call to isStartupManagerDelegateTriggered?  Please provide context there - is it happening after a network request or something else asynch?

Comment: Hi @danh Sorry for the delayed reply. It stil isn't working. I'm gonna try a NSNotification, perhaps that works.